# GitHub/nbviewer skip cells in Jupyter Notebook document

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbviewer

I can't find a solution as to why when displaying my code in Jupyter Notebook, GitHub and nbviewer doesn't recalculate some cells. On localhost everything works as expected. This refers to the "Backward Elimintaion" section (cells 24-26) under the links.

[nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/github/Jacek89/Data-Analysis-Training/blob/bbdf2cbe015acff2e403ed720c29f4a35ef94f1b/Chapter%203%20-%20Regression/3.1%20Laptop%20price%20prediction%20with%20Linear%20Regression/Laptop%20prices.ipynb#5)

[GitHub](https://github.com/Jacek89/Data-Analysis-Training/blob/bbdf2cbe015acff2e403ed720c29f4a35ef94f1b/Chapter%203%20-%20Regression/3.1%20Laptop%20price%20prediction%20with%20Linear%20Regression/Laptop%20prices.ipynb)

Comment: The code [here](https://github.com/Jacek89/Data-Analysis-Training/blob/bbdf2cbe015acff2e403ed720c29f4a35ef94f1b/Chapter%203%20-%20Regression/3.1%20Laptop%20price%20prediction%20with%20Linear%20Regression/Laptop%20prices.ipynb#L1081) clearly shows no output being displayed for that `print()` statement at code cell #25. Contrast with the one for `"execution_count": 27,` a little ways after that clearly shows content in `"outputs": [`. So there is nothing for nbviewer's rendering of the static notebook or GitHub's **preview** to show. Both of those are showing results already calculated in ....

Comment: <continued> previous active notebook sessions where that was run. You could have ended up with that if after running the entire notebook, you or someone else went back up and cleared the output from those three code cells. nbviewer and GitHub's preview are only displaying **statically** what was pre-saved from the active Pyhton kernel. They don't run any code, with the exception of javascript based things like Plotly that it can run in nbviewer (not in Github's preview though).

Comment: <continued> "On localhost everything works as expected."  So ideally after you re-ran the Jupyter `.ipynb` file on your local system using Jupyter, you'd check there is a result from that `print()` statement, for example, and then you'd save and push the changes to GitHub. nbviewer will be able to pick them up later. Sometimes it takes a while to get the new changes in nbviewer because of browser caching, and it is easier to check in another browser or on another computer.

Comment: @Wayne thanks for the explanation, everything works now